# Defining a variable outside of SQL Script

Tags: sql

If anyone knows a way it would be greatly appreciated. So I have a lot of paths in many of my SQL scripts and the beginning of the paths are all the same. I'm thinking of cleaning up the hardcoded paths and changing it to a variable where all my SQL scripts can call the string variable where it stores my beginning path and concatenate it to the full path. So the variable can be stored in a .json, .sh, or even .sql if possible. I'm not picky about the solution as long as it works. Thanks!

Comment: How are you running these scripts?  One option is to add a new table with your global params. Then select them into your other scripts

Comment: So I add all the sql scripts in a specific order to a shell script to perform ETL, QA, QC and etc. I was thinking of doing that, but I was curious if there was any other ways of doing it because I work on a team and it's very tedious for the next person to go into every single sql script file and changing the paths manually.

Comment: Don't those scripts support relative paths? If so, you don't need any variable at all. For details about how to pass variables to scripts, it may help to know what database it is and what tool you are using for executing those scripts.

Comment: So the database I use is Postgresql and I just use the terminal to execute the shell scripts that includes all the SQL scripts.